# Dynamically merge two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Background**

I have two dataframes, one contains some unrelated columns and forecast sales volume (x1, x2, ...)

```
date        ColA        Colb    x1  x2  x3  …
1/01/2022   Apple       Cat     703 750 273 738
2/01/2022   Banana      Dog     540 908 397 726
3/01/2022   Orange      Pig     444 835 258 986
4/01/2022   Blueberry   Rat     969 582 393 911
5/01/2022   Watermelon  Bird    426 950 321 337
…
```

The other contains product prices and the day they started to be sold in store.

```
product start_date  price
x1      2/01/2022   0.9
x2      4/01/2022   0.5
x3      4/01/2022   1.2
…       5/01/2022   1.0
```

**What I'm trying to do**

I am trying to:

1. Zero out forecast sales volume, if it's before the Product Sales Start Date
2. Multiply Forecast Sales volume by the product price to forecast revenue

**Desired Result**

```
date        ColA        Colb    x1      x2  x3      …
1/01/2022   Apple       Cat     0       0   0       0
2/01/2022   Banana      Dog     486     0   0       0
3/01/2022   Orange      Pig     399.6   0   0       0
4/01/2022   Blueberry   Rat     872.1   291 471.6   0
5/01/2022   Watermelon  Bird    383.4   475 385.2   337
…
```

**Problem**

The problem is the number of products varies. I am currently doing it manually editing my code each time to do this sum. Multiplying by the price is easy enough, but the Start_Date is tough, I don't know an easier way to do this dynamically. Below is an example of my current code.

Note: for the most part the two dataframes will be in the same order (i.e. x1, x2, x3, etc)

**Code Example**

```py
import pandas as pd

# Dataframe one example
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'Date': pd.Series(['2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-04', '2022-01-05'], dtype='datetime64[ns]'),
    'ColA': ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Blueberry', 'Watermelon'],
    'ColB': ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Pig', 'Rat', 'Bird'],
    'x1': [703, 540, 444, 969, 426],
    'x2': [750, 908, 835, 582, 950],
    'x3': [273, 397, 258, 393, 321],
    'x4': [738, 726, 986, 911, 337]
})

# Dataframe two example
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'Product': ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4'],
    'Start_Date': pd.Series(['2022-01-02', '2022-01-04', '2022-01-04', '2022-01-05'], dtype='datetime64[ns]'),
    'Price': [0.9, 0.5, 1.2, 1.0]
})
df2.set_index('Product')

# Multipy by Price
df3 = df1.iloc[:, 3:7].multiply(df2[['Price']].values.T, axis='columns')
df3['sd1'] = df2['Start_Date'].iloc[0]
df3['sd2'] = df2['Start_Date'].iloc[1]
df3['sd3'] = df2['Start_Date'].iloc[2]
df3['sd4'] = df2['Start_Date'].iloc[3]
df3 = df1[['Date', 'ColA', 'ColB']].merge(df3, left_index=True, right_index=True)
print(df3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code snippet should solve your purpose :) :

```py
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

# Dataframe one example
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'Date': pd.Series(['2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-04', '2022-01-05'], dtype='datetime64[ns]'),
    'ColA': ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Blueberry', 'Watermelon'],
    'ColB': ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Pig', 'Rat', 'Bird'],
    'x1': [703, 540, 444, 969, 426],
    'x2': [750, 908, 835, 582, 950],
    'x3': [273, 397, 258, 393, 321],
    'x4': [738, 726, 986, 911, 337]
})

# Dataframe two example
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'Product': ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4'],
    'Start_Date': pd.Series(['2022-01-02', '2022-01-04', '2022-01-04', '2022-01-05'], dtype='datetime64[ns]'),
    'Price': [0.9, 0.5, 1.2, 1.0]
})
df2.set_index('Product', inplace=True)

# Multipy by Price and Generate final df
cols_to_work = [col for col in df1.columns if col.startswith('x')]
datetime_col = 'Date'
datetime_col_df2 = 'Start_Date'

for idx, rows in df1.iterrows():
    for col in cols_to_work:
        if rows[datetime_col] >= df2[datetime_col_df2].loc[col]:
            # print(rows[datetime_col], df2['Start_Date'].loc[col], rows[datetime_col] >= df2['Start_Date'].loc[col])
            # print(col, '-', df1[col].loc[idx], ' * ', df2['Price'].loc[col], ' = ', df1[col].loc[idx] * df2['Price'].loc[col])
            df1[col].loc[idx] = df1[col].loc[idx] * df2['Price'].loc[col]
        else:
            df1[col].loc[idx] = 0

df1.head()
```

OUTPUT:

```
        Date        ColA  ColB     x1     x2     x3     x4
0 2022-01-01       Apple   Cat    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
1 2022-01-02      Banana   Dog  486.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
2 2022-01-03      Orange   Pig  399.6    0.0    0.0    0.0
3 2022-01-04   Blueberry   Rat  872.1  291.0  471.6    0.0
4 2022-01-05  Watermelon  Bird  383.4  475.0  385.2  337.0
```